# Why is the Kurkavon mentioned?

Tags: talmud-gemara, tractate-brachot, parts-of-the-body

In Masheches Berachos [daf 61b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.61b.1?lang=bi), the gemara mentions various body parts and their respective functions. It seems that the gemara is referring to human body parts, based off the gemaras premise (on [daf 61a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.61a.28-29?lang=bi)) that the two kidneys provide good and evil advice, respectively.

Within the list, the gemara mentions the *kurkavon* (the 3rd stomach of birds that grinds food). Why does the gemara mention an animal organ when the gemara implies that it's only talking about human beings?

Comment: @interested please do not be discouraged by downvotes, the main point is the learning (I hope). It takes time to get used to this site. It is imperative to show sources since no one knows who you are and sources are the only thing that is reliable . So if you have a good answer just make sure its source is written so people can see it. I would like to see your answer.  All the best

Comment: Because the heilige kurkivan....

Answer (score 2):

There is a mistake in rashi as this sefer says.
from sefer devash by shabsi ben dov ber halprin
[image]

Comment: As with your other answers, please cite the source where you got it from.

Comment: @interested Please [edit] to include, in English text, the content of your answer and the identity of its author. If you can link directly to your online source, that would be very helpful, too. The goal here is to provide information in a way that is accessible to anyone who's interested in the question, including those who don't know Hebrew, and including those who can't see images. Torah ideas deserve the best possible presentation.

Comment: Upvoted ,tx,just to note he says maybe it's a mistake .

Comment: Ok you win. This again is the correct answer. The simplest is usually the best. I only quoted the other one to prove it is a good question since others also ask it even though they dont know the answer. which was taken from Ovos R  Noson.